# Compare elements of a character list with a character input

Tags: python-3.x

I have a question, I have a character list similar to this:

```
 letras_lista = ['gcjcf', 'afadd', 'ibfah', 'ihdha', 'cdigc', 'kaaci', 'ihiga', 'jbjji', 'hbjjj', 'bcdjg', 'ieika']
```

And I have a two character input like this:

```
 orden = 'ah'
```

For this I created this code:

```
 cont = 0
for i in letras_lista:#lista que puse de ejemplo
    lista = [i]
    for x in lista:
        if orden in x:#patron a comparar
            cont +=1
print(cont)
```

Could you tell me if there is a way to optimize the code, I am new to programming and I don't know many ways to do it.
Beforehand thank you very much

Comment: Delete `lista = [i]`, remove the inner loop, and compare directly to `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way is to take advantage of the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and sum over the condition:

```
cont = sum(orden in x for x in letras_lista)
```

Here is a step by step way to get from your implementation to mine:

First, notice that your inner loop is iterating over a list of length 1. Not only that, but you artificially constructed this list `lista`. That means that you can get rid of `lista` and the inner loop, and just run the conditional:

```
cont = 0
for i in letras_lista:
    if orden in i:
        cont += 1
```

Now notice that the boolean value `orden in i` is equivalent to  what you want to add to `cont`. Since `True == 1` in python, and `False == 0`, you can write

```
cont = 0
for i in letras_lista:
    cont += (orden in i)
```

Hopefully it is now clear how you can place the boolean condition directly into the `sum` call.

Answer (score 1):

`print(len([i for i in letras_lista if orden in i]))`